# Org-agenda de-duplicate items

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I've got the `org-agenda` showing all the deadlines and scheduled items for the current week. For items where the deadline is later in the week, they are shown both on the due date and the current day. How do I disable showing tasks with future deadlines on the current date?

As an example, here is my current org-agenda:

```
Tuesday     6 March 2018
  work:       Scheduled:  TODO Email class telling them to all finish the assignment
  work:       Scheduled:  TODO Review survey
  work:       Scheduled:  TODO Prepare background info slides
  work:       In   1 d.:  TODO Create exam 2
  work:       In   1 d.:  TODO Encryption slides
  work:       In   1 d.:  TODO Encryption lab
Wednesday   7 March 2018
  work:       Deadline:   TODO Create exam 2
  work:       Deadline:   TODO Encryption slides
  work:       Deadline:   TODO Encryption lab
```

Notice that the last three items under today are duplicated on their due date of Wednesday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to customise the variable

```
org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled
```

setting it to "Remove prewaring if entry is scheduled".  (In a `setq` that would be the value `t`).

For example

```
* TODO something
  DEADLINE: <2018-03-16 Fri> SCHEDULED: <2018-03-14 Wed>
```

then appears in a weakly agenda as

```
Week-agenda (W11-W12):
Wednesday  14 March 2018
  k:          Scheduled:  TODO something
Thursday   15 March 2018
Friday     16 March 2018
  k:          Deadline:   TODO something
Saturday   17 March 2018
Sunday     18 March 2018
Monday     19 March 2018 W12
Tuesday    20 March 2018
```

The possible settings for this variable are

- "Always show prewarning" (`nil`)
- "Remove prewarning prior to scheduled date" (`pre-scheduled`)
- "Remove prewarning if entry is scheduled" (`t`)
- "Restart prewarning N days before deadline" (integer)

These do not affect showing the deadline on the due date.